# FileAppender not writing anything in log4j

Tags: log4j, osgi

I have a small problem using log4j and `FileAppender`. When I am using `ConsoleAppender`, everything is working well but `FileAppender` won't ever produce a file (or write into a file). Moreover, I have no errors concerning log4j in the osgi console.

Here's my configuration :

```
# main link (console or file, depending on what we want)
# log4j.category.com.foo=DEBUG, console
  log4j.category.com.foo=DEBUG, file
# log4j.category.com.foo=DEBUG, console, file

#  console logging
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# file logging
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\Users\\foo\\some_file.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Note that the `ConversionPattern` attributes are exactly the same in the two appenders.

I have tried to change the `File` argument to write the log in the "run" directory but it didn't do anything.
I also tried to add `log4j.appender.file.ImmediateFlush=true` without success.

Have I missed something (obvious ?) somewhere ? It sound strange that log4j isn't even able to write a simple log in a file....

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you show the first line of the file ? Are you sure you've connected the root logger (for instance) to the file logging ?

Comment: Hi, I have added the first line in the post. I guess the problem shouldn't be linked with that because it works with "console" as appender. Of course, I am sure that this file is used in the process (if I change DEBUG to INFO it does change the console output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace :

```
 log4j.category.com.foo=DEBUG, console
```

By :

```
 log4j.category.com.foo=DEBUG, console, file
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I realize I was probably not clear in my explanations. As written in the comment above the first line., the problem does not come from this line. When I try to output in "file" I use "DEBUG, file", when I try to output in console I use "DEBUG, console" and of course "DEBUG, console, file" for both appenders. I updated the post so it is more understandable.

Comment: So sorry, I read too quickly. Have you tried specifying the append value ? log4j.appender.file.Append=true, for instance.

Comment: And, while we're at it, be sure the "com.foo" correspond to a REAL package in your application :). (You never know, you might be as distracted as I am sometimes...)

Comment: Hi, thanks for everything. Actually I managed to make it working by changing "C:\\Users\\...." into "c:/Users/...". Apparently, it seems to work only with normal "/", small letter for "c" and no relative path...

Comment: Weird... I use relative path (and RollingFileAppenders). Well, the most important is that it works :). Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but for other Googlers...
For me it was simply using wrong package.
I used org.apache.logging.log4j instead org.apache.log4j
If you are using Maven use this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```