# Log4j's RollingFileAppender doesn't create a file

Tags: java, spring, log4j, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application which uses Log4j. I've set up RollingFileAppender and ConsoleAppender. The second one works fine, but RollingFile Appender doesn't create a file.

Here's a file with properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=log4j-application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Any ideas will be very appreciated.

Comment: try this org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender instead of org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

Comment: it didn't make any difference

Comment: Check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212368/fileappender-not-writing-anything-in-log4j

Comment: Do I have to write somewhere in a project, that I use RollingFileAppender? Maybe I didn't set up everything?

Comment: log4j-application.log must be created in your project root folder.Where are checking it?

Comment: Actually I override this property in a script which I use to run the application. The log file should be written to /home directory. (when I didn't  override this property, it didn't work either)

Answer (score 0):

Use this configurarion

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, consoleAppender, fileAppender

log4j.appender.consoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.fileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.fileAppender.File=demoApplication.log
```

For more info visit this link http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/08/how-to-configure-log4j-using-properties-file/

Comment: Have you added jar files properly?Which jar files you are using?Add slf4j-log4j , slf4j-api and log4j jar files.

Comment: I use Spring Boot, all the libraries are included in my application's jar

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you can try the following for daily-logging

```
log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=logfile.log
log4j.appender.logfile.Threshold = INFO
log4j.appender.logfile.DatePattern='_'yyyyMMdd'.log'
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%-d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}  [ %t:%r ] - [ %p ]  %m%n
```

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately it doesn't work in my program